# Ramdajs - how to combine pipe and function to update an object

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

I have a function that accepts two parameters.

```
const myfunction = (xyz) => async(param) => {
   return "some value " + xyz + param.a;
}
```

and a pipe with an object as parameter,

```
R.pipe(

)({"a":"a value"});
```

How to add new attribute to the object with the function returned value?

Expected output:

```
{
  "a": "a value",
  "b": "some value xyz a value"
}
```

Tried the below, but parameter error

```
R.pipe(
  R.assoc("b", myfunction("xyz")),
)({ "a" :"a value"});



R.pipe(
      R.assoc("b", myfunction("xyz")(R.identity)),
    )({ "a" :"a value"});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything really built into Ramda for this.  We can write it atop several Ramda functions, like this:

```js
const myfunction = (xyz) => async (param) => {
   return "some value " + xyz + param .a
}

const foo = (param) => 
  myfunction ('xyz') (param) .then (flip (assoc ('b')) (param))


foo ({a: 'a value'}) .then (console .log)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {flip, assoc} = R </script>
```

But it's not at all clear that this is in any way better than a vanilla JS version such as this:

```js
const foo = (param) => 
  myfunction ('xyz') (param) .then (v => ({...param, b: v}))
```

(and I'm a founder and big fan of Ramda; it simply doesn't try to solve all problems.)

However, there is an interesting abstraction of either of these, to create our own combinator which handles the overall flow of `(f, g) => (x) => f (x) .then (g (x))`.  As it feels relatively close to `pipe`ing and because there is a [strong tradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Mock_a_Mockingbird) of naming combinators after birds, I will call this `piper`, short for "sandpiper".  Abstracting out that, we can simplify `foo` to look like this:

```js
const piper = (f, g) => (p) => f (p) .then (g (p))

const myfunction = (xyz) => async (param) => {
   return "some value " + xyz + param .a
}

const foo = piper (myfunction ('xyz'), flip (assoc ('b')))

foo ({a: 'a value'}) .then (console .log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {flip, assoc} = R </script>
```

This can be a very powerful technique, abstracting out the logical skeleton of our function to be used in multiple places.  Of course it adds nothing to just a single function like this, but it lets us find commonalities with future code.